# Command not Found in centos 6

Tags: centos, package-management

While installing `gambas`, I am facing some problems.

The list of commands I need to execute follow.

```
$> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gambas-team/gambas-daily
$> sudo apt-get update
$> sudo apt-get install gambas3
```

But when running the first command it shows the following.

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Comment: i think it is not running ? how can i test ?

Comment: CentOS is RPM-Based Linux Distribution, use `yum` instead of `apt-get`.

Comment: i tried with "YUM INSTALL GAMBAS3" But it shows like this        Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * extras: mirror.tadu.vn
 * updates: mirrors.nhanhoa.com
Setting up Install Process
No package gambas3 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [gambas3 Compilation & Installation documentation](http://gambaswiki.org/wiki/install?nh&l=en#t1), there is no direct distro available in centOS 6 to install `gambas3`.

If you still wants to install, you will have to manually compile and install it. For this, I think, you should try the instructions for Fedora 13, 14, 15 & 16 given in [Gambas 3.0 compilation instructions](http://gambaswiki.org/wiki/install/fedora?nh#t8) documentation for Fedora.

Answer (score 2):

[APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)(Advanced Packaging Tool) is the default packager used with Debian based distribution
 Whereas **CentOS** is [**RPM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager)(Redhat Package Manager) based distribution and [Yellowdog Updater, Modified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified) (**Yum**) is the default package manager [used](https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum) in CentOS

So, Either you've to add repository and manage package with `yum` or you've to install `apt` package manager for CentOS!

I recommend visiting first  [package management](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos#head-70ff04f00f6b441f231663b09d7716f4f771a436) for CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

By default, CentOS uses yum to install packages.

Instead of using apt-get, you run:

`sudo yum update
sudo yum install gambas3`

Comment: it shows like this                                                                                                        Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * extras: mirror.tadu.vn
 * updates: mirrors.nhanhoa.com
Setting up Install Process
No package gambas3 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: It happened because `gambas3` is not available in your mirrors links. By the way, I think you should go to gambas3 page and read the installation instruction

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use apt-get with centos, this command is being used in Ubuntu. So you can use `yum` or `rpm` command in Centos to install rpm binaries.

However, the program you mentioned is not available in RPM based binary. So the only way is, get the source code from `gambas3` official site and build in centos distro.

**EDIT :** I am not sure if it's work but you can download and try to install RPM available for [fedora](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&limit=1&srodzaj=1&dl=40&search=gambas3&dist[]=99&dist[]=96&dist[]=92&dist[]=94&dist[]=79&field[]=1&field[]=2) .

```
rpm -ivh /path/filename.rpm
```